# Showing AngularJS i18n date and time formats for users

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

For displaying date and time in internationalised formats from ISO string, I'm using date filter like this:

```
ng-bind="mydate | date: 'mediumDate'"
```

But when user is allowed to enter date in the input, I'd like to display current date format, so for example, in en-gb it would be 'd MMM y'.

Is see this is stored in the i18n localisation file under "mediumDate": "d MMM y" but how would I retrieve that info and display it for a user?

Answer (score 0):

Info from localised file is stored in object:

```
$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS
```

So all I need to do is to expose required info.